# How to getElement of an "a" tag within a "class"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-scraping

I've been wrestling with vanilla javascript for GetElementsBy(ID/Tag/Span) for some time, and was wondering if any of you have encountered this or know a solution to this problem.

I'm trying to getElementBy(...) for 3 innerHTML texts in the DOM that looks like this:

```html
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item">
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item">
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item">
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
```

Ultimately, I want to grab all three texts inside the text tag using GetElementsBy(...). What is the right approach to get this data?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('ul.main_Bucket>li.id_category>span.id_device>a')` is the most "specific" way to target those 3 elements - then you can iterate through the result to grab the text content of those elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is pretty messy. I tried to clean it up in the example below, and added some distinct text for each bit of text you're trying to extract so it's more illustrative that we're grabbing 3 different links' texts. The code iterates over the anchors found, and uses the same highly specific selector @Jaromanda X wrote in his comment.

Click the "Run" button below to see it in action.

```js
let anchors = document.querySelectorAll('ul.main_Bucket>li.id_category>span.id_device>a');
console.log(anchors.length, "anchors found");
anchors.forEach((anchor)=>console.log(anchor.innerText));
```

```html
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item"></span>
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">ONE: This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item"></span>
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">TWO: This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class ="main_Bucket">
  <li class="id_category">
    <span class="id_item"></span>
    <span class="id_device">
      <a href="somesite.com">THREE: This is the Data I want to Grab</a>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great job Marc - this is clean.

Comment: Thanks, @ChronoJigga. Please mark the answer accepted if it met your needs.